# Restric Toolbar to scroll up on showing softInputKeyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, android-toolbar

I am designing a layout for SignIn activity. I had to give fixed weights to my layout containers. My issue is that the toolbar scrolls up when `softInputKeyboard` is shown.

I have tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible"` but none of the options work for me.

Also setting root layout to `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` didn't helped.

This
[image]

desceibes my problem.

And Xml Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="tpltrakker.tplmap.ActivitySignIn">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_sign_in"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/app_color_greenish"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="35"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/title_hello"
                android:textColor="@color/app_color_greenish"
                android:textSize="30sp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="12"
                android:text="@string/label_sign_in"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="28"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:weightSum="10">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_google"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4.5"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/google"
                    android:text="@string/button_google"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ButtonGoogle" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_fb"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4.5"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/facebook"
                    android:text="@string/button_facebook"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ButtonFacebook" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10">


                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@color/divider_color" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/label_or"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_color_greenish"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:background="@color/divider_color" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/email" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_email"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/password" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_password"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="35">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login_new"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ButtonGreen" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_forget_pass"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_login_new"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/action_forget_pass"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/app_color_greenish" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_signup_new"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_up"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/app_color_greenish" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_terms"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:text="@string/action_term"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/app_color_greenish" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add in AndroidManifest.xml for your activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

check out [this article on the Android developers' site](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) which describes how the to handles the soft keyboard.

The `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute can be used to specify what happens on a per-activity basis: whether the layout is resized or whether it scrolls etc.

Comment: making adjustPan|adjustResize at the same makes layout to remain same when keyboard is shown. None of the layouts are paning or resizing. How ever I want just my Toolbar not to pan when keyboard is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line into activity registered in AndroidManifest.xml:-

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: doesn't work. t makes all the layouts to resize themselves whereas the issue remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Change your toolbar xml, and add `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_sign_in"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/app_color_greenish"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```